# Multivalue Custom Dimensions in Universal Analytics through Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Adding Custom Dimensions to Universal Analytics via Tag Manager is generally a straightforward process. I've run into an issue populating a Custom Dimension multiple times on the same page. For example, the Custom Dimension is "Page Topics". There are multiple Page Topics to a page. The Page Topic is set up as a Hit Level dimension. The values are in a pipe delimited javascript variable illustrated below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var userType='super premium member';var logInStatus='logged in';var userSex='male';var pageTopics="Celebration | Holiday | Party";</script>
```

I'm parsing that value and sending it to GTM with the following code which is placed on the page using GTM:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WR90.jpg)

Tag Manager is configured to accept those parameters as part of a custom dimension and pass it via an Event Tag. The Event Tag has no event params configured (they're optional) so that bogus events do not end up in the system. This configuration can be seen below:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdrCu.jpg)

All of the tags are firing but no data is getting to GA. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Per Blexy's answer below, I'll update the event fields to be filled out. I'm going to use a Data Collection category and Topic Tracking action. If I have further needs for data collection, they can all go under this category and be largely ignored for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks great except that the Event Tag you're referencing has two REQUIRED parameters: category and action. Take a look at Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview).

Add both a category and action, and you'll be seeing those dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're absolutely right, I had been confused because the Tag Manager platform indicates that all of the event fields are optional. This is because the Universal Analytics tag exposes similar fields when used for an event as it does the Page View usage.